# Where is this verse found?

Tags: scripture, puranas, smriti

Pranam
"Guru uktam api na grahyam yad anarthe artha kalpanam"
Even the words of Guru should be rejected if they are immoral..
I think it is from 7th canto bhagavatam prahlad maharaj's teachings..i dont know
Please point me out the source..
Thanks

Comment: I searched but could not find this quote in Srimad Bhagavatam 7th skandha.

Comment: Thanks Sir...Do you know any verses which forbid wife from obeying immoral orders from husband?